# Custom ordering of records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table such as http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e4f6f which contains records that need to be reported on an Excel using SSIS.

However, the ordering of records needs to be custom.

Such as below

```
AID BID CID CurrencyID  ClassID Year MetricID   Value               ReferenceID
220 1   3   6           1147    2012    C1      653465.751842658967 V001
220 1   3   6           1147    2012    C2      0.000000000000      V001
220 1   3   6           1156    2012    C1      1151019.50078003120 V001
220 1   3   6           1156    2012    C2      0.000000000000      V001
```

As you can see the records are grouped such that they are ordered on  ***ReferenceID*** first and then all the other dimension keys except the ***MetricID***. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What custom ordering do you want to use?  Can you show us some sample output?

Comment: What is the problem with your sql query?

Comment: Your example is too simplified. What's wrong with what you have already? `ORDER BY ReferenceID, BID, CID, CurrencyID, ClassID, Year`

Comment: The sample output is in the question above.
As you can see MetricID is ordered differently than the rest.

Comment: Your sample data and expected result do not match.

Comment: The `custom sort` has to be done at the presentation layer,and not in DB.

Comment: Updated the Schema on fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e4f6f . 
As declared earlier I report on Excel using SSIS i do not have a UI presentation layer

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [FactValidationResult]
ORDER BY ReferenceID, AID,BID, CID, CurrencyID,Year, ClassID, MetricID
`

Comment: Thanks for this Felix this works.. I was over-complicating this from my end I think... I can mark your answer if you write it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `MetricID` as the last column in your `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM [FactValidationResult]
ORDER BY 
    ReferenceID, 
    AID,
    BID,
    CID,
    CurrencyID,
    Year,
    ClassID,
    MetricID
```